# add visitors browser info ip on simple php dom parser

Tags: php, dom

how to add visitors browser info ip on simple php dom parser. [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: What effort have to made to get it working?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible, you can add it in function you like. Here are example:

```
        $header = array();
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] =  "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] =  "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.


    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7');
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar); 
    curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);
    curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```